# Drag multiple images from Qt Application to MS Word

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, ms-word

I want to put not one but multiple images into a QMimeData to drop into MS Word.

The interface doesn't support this (multiple calls of setImageData() overwrite each other).

Can this be done with QMimeData? Maybe with HTML? But where do you then put the images? Or do I have to do this with a native Windows API?

Thx

Comment: What type of data are you dragging?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a QWebView and load only your image to the page, the image will be draggable all over the desktop.